# Getting error using Bootstrap Tags Input for particular input field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, tags, field

I'm getting the error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'undefined'
```

in javascript file `bootstrap-tagsinput.js`.

```
var retVal = tagsinput[arg1](arg2);
```

`arg1` and `arg2` is undefined

using following code:

```
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington" data-role="tagsinput" id="article_tags"/>

<script src="../../Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="../../Scripts/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/js/typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function () {
$('input').tagsinput();

    // Adding custom typeahead support using http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js
    $('input').tagsinput('input').typeahead({
      prefetch: '../../Content/json/data.json'
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {
        this.tagsinput('add', datum.value);
        this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
    }, $('input')));
});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery?

Comment: yes i am including jquery :<script src="../../Scripts/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Are you including jQuery *before* bootstrap.min.js? If so, is it loading (check your path)?